# Meaning of "discriminatory disinterest" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Whether motivated by outright prejudice or simple discriminatory disinterest, ...

This sentence-piece is taken from a text written on the illegalization of cannabis, stating that Mexican immigration was the reason cannabis was illegalized in the United States.

Given how *discriminatory disinterest* is being contrasted to *outright prejudice*, it would seem that *discriminatory disinterest* is a kind of discrimination not driven by emotional imperatives (like xenophobia, ideology, racism, etc.), but rather other motivations that simply happen to involve racial discrimination (if e.g. discriminating against Mexicans would somehow be economically favorable).

However, I don't quite see how *discriminatory disinterest* means that. Does the *disinterest* perhaps refer to the lack of actual interest in the actual race/ethnicity at hand?

Here's a [link](https://druglibrary.org/schaffer/library/studies/vlr/vlr2.htm) to the text it was taken from. You can find the sentence in the first paragraph of chapter 1: *Rationale in the West: Class Legislation*

Comment: Something can be racist even if it seems not to have a racial element or its proponents claim it applies to everyone regardless of race. For instance prohibiting something that Mexicans do a lot and non-Mexicans seldom do; bans on face coverings that discriminate against Muslims, or requirements on headwear that discriminate against turban-wearing Sikhs are other obvious examples of measures that don't appear racist but may have racist effects. So a measure which appears impartial is actually racist. This is really more a question for the politics board though.

Comment: @StuartF I am aware that something can be racially discriminatory without having a racial element, as you say. I included this in my post. My question is, what does the author mean with "discriminatory disinterest"? I then proposed this racial discrimination without a racial element thing that you mentioned as a possible meaning. Whether or not it is the meaning would depend on the semantics of *disinterest*, *discriminatory* and *discriminatory disinterest*, landing it within the scope of this site. There was no political question here, although the subject matter of the text is political.

Comment: "Outright prejudice" is used there to convey positively and actively punishing or injuring with bigotry, like its Latin root "praeiūdicāre" means "to injure." "Discriminatory disinterest" contrastingly conveys bigotry that isn't positive or active but is negative and passive by simply withholding interest you would otherwise give. "Outright prejudice" introduces harmful action. "Discriminatory disinterest" simply allows harm to come on its own by withholding action or taking away action generally provided to others in that situation.

Comment: By analogy, outright prejudice is to discriminatory disinterest as abuse is to neglect.

Comment: *Discriminatory disinterest* is not a well established, set phrase. Any interpretation of it that may be offered (Mr Harman's is probably on the right track) thus amounts to an explanation of this particular text, rather than an elucidation of a general feature of English language and usage.

Comment: @jsw29 I can agree that since the phrase isn't really cemented, to understand its meaning in this case, it would require some analysis of the text to understand the phrases usage, via its context. That analysis would require knowledge that isn't strictly about how the English language is used in general, but rather how the English language is used in political texts, which is why this question would probably fit on a politics site. However, how English is used in an political text, is still English usage. It is a specific, non-general use, but it still is a use. There *is* a terminology tag.

Comment: @A.Kvåle, there cannot be an explanation of how the phrase is used in political **texts** generally,  because it is not a part of the well established terminology of that field either; an explanation offered can only be an explanation of how it is used in **this** particular text. The distinction that the author is trying to make seems to roughly correspond to what is, in legal contexts, usually expressed as the distinction between discriminatory intent and discriminatory impact.

Comment: @jsw29 Is it correct that you're saying that the lack of establishment of the phrase make its use sufficiently idiolectical to not be considered "English"? Because even if English idiolects are components of the English language, I would agree that practically they cannot be within the scope of this site.

Comment: @A.Kvåle, I think that the regular contributors to this site would probably agree that idiolects are off topic (such questions were characterised as 'too localised' in the past), but I suspect that they may not always agree on whether this or that question (that includes this one) is about an idiolect. If you are interested in getting some more elaborate answers to the question you raised in the last comment, you may wish to ask it on the meta- part of this site.

Comment: @jsw29 Well after thinking about it, and doing some quick searches for *discriminatory disinterest*, I am of the opinion that any use of the word would be idiolectical, because it really is quite badly established. It would be nice to ask that question on the meta though, to gain some thoughts on it. Do you think the word is idiolectical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read it is "outright prejudice" is active in this case "the legislature actively designing legislation to harm Mexicans"

Discriminatory disinterest is still prejudice but it is passive "the legislature simply not caring, taking no effort to prevent legislation from being harmful to Mexicans"

A legislator drafted a piece of legislation that was deliberately harmful to Mexicans (outright prejudice), and the other legislators who probably knew this did nothing to prevent it from becoming law despite that being within their power or responsibility (discriminatory disinterest)

The distinction being drawn is between active and passive prejudice.